# Validation message not showing when using keypress event to identify enterkey press

Tags: jquery

I am using a form for getting name and description. When the user tries to update the details, I am displaying validation message to show "Name already exists".
I am using using the below code to show the message:

```
$('#name').bind("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        updateName();
        return false;
    }
});
```

'function updateName() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Name/name",
            data: postData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.NameExists) {
                    $("#name").html("name already exists");

}'

When I am pressing enter the validation message shows, when I am releasing enter key the message disappears. I have tried keydown event too. But it is not working.

Anyone help me with your experience. Thanks!

Comment: please include all relevant code to question.

Comment: I have tried your but it is working file, Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/ssndnxju/2/ . Are you missing any code ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try as follow:-

```
$('#name').bind("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        updateName();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: can you add explanation as to why this should be used?

Answer (score 1):

Assumption of markup: `<input type="text" id="name" />`

```
$('#name').on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        updateName();
    }
});
```

- "keypress" would fire the event multiple times if held down.
- Use "keyup" to fire when it is released.
- Use the `e.which` as jQuery normalizes the key value to this.

No need to return false if you prevent default - do you also wish to prevent propagation?

What if a user tabs out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this structure...

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    // enter pressed
  }
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can you add explanation as to why this should be used?